# Android home button arrow direction

Tags: java, android

The layout can direct to right when I'am using the arabic language but the home button arrow cannot to direct to right thanks.

[image]

Comment: As you currently have Arabic so all layouts will be changes as per arabic language.

Comment: give RTL support in manifeast.xml like

android:supportsRtl="true"

Answer (score 1):

From [Native RTL support in Android 4.2](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:%20blogspot/hsDu%20(Android%20Developers%20Blog))

To take advantage of RTL layout mirroring, simply make the following changes to your app:

- Declare in your app manifest that your app supports RTL mirroring.
  Specifically, add `android:supportsRtl="true"` to the `<application>` element in your manifest file.
- Change all of your app's "left/right" layout properties to new "start/end" equivalents.
  If you are targeting your app to Android 4.2 (the app's targetSdkVersion or minSdkVersion is 17 or higher), then you should use “start” and “end” instead of “left” and “right”. For example, android:paddingLeft should become android:paddingStart.
  If you want your app to work with versions earlier than Android 4.2 (the app's targetSdkVersion or minSdkVersion is 16 or less), then you should add “start” and end” in addition to “left” and “right”. For example, you’d use both android:paddingLeft and android:paddingStart.

Comment: my layout was running fine with direction but when I changed the package of google map from compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
 to   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0' the direction of arrow cannot direct to right .. thanks.

Comment: Try downgrading the compile version.

Comment: Have you changed the layout properties as mentioned in point 2?

Comment: in your xml where you have declared your views. Go through my comment slowly & try to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

It happens because Arabic language is read from right to left. The arrow is set properly, only thing you need to do is provide RTL support to your app.

To provide RTL support, specifically, add `android:supportsRtl="true"` to the `<application>` element in your manifest file

Comment: my layout was running fine with direction but when I changed the package of google map from compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0' to compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0' the direction of arrow cannot direct to right .. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just give RTL support in manifeast.xml like android:supportsRtl="true" 
under the application tag

Comment: android:supportsRtl="true" I was written but layout has the same problem....
my layout was running fine with direction but when I changed the package of google map from compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0' to compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0' the direction of arrow cannot direct to right .. thanks.

Comment: @JamalAl-abbadi have you added it as dependency?

Comment: @Akshay Tilekar yes

Comment: just give a try,may be it's conflicting.You need to put the apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' line below your dependencies block - this allows the plugin to determine what version of Play services you are using

Comment: @ Akshay Tilekar ok